# Tic Tac Toe in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, tic-tac-toe

I'm a beginner and just finished my first Tic Tac Toe program. I was looking to get some feedback on some of the portions that seem a bit repetitive. Is there a way to make this more dry vs. hard coding?

```
///////TicTacToe///////////

//////////BOARD ASSIGNMENT////////////
var a = "a";
var b = "b";
var c = "c";
var d = "d";
var e = "e";
var f = "f";
var g = "g";
var h = "h";
var i = "i";

play();

function buildBoard() {
    var board = "=======" + "\n" + a + "|" + b + "|" + c +"\n" +
    d + "|" + e + "|" + f + "\n" +
    g + "|" +  h + "|" + i + "\n" + "=======";
    console.log(board);
    return board;
    }

/////////PLAYER INPUT///////////
function getInput(){
    console.log("You are X, the computer is O" + "\n" +
        "X goes first");
    return prompt("You are X, the computer is O" + "\n" +
        "X goes first");
}
//////////CPU MOVE GENERATOR & VALIDATOR///////////
function randomNumber() {
    var random = Math.random();
    if (random > 0.89) {
        if (a !== 'X' && a !== 'O') {
        a = "O";
        return a;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.78) {
        if (b !== 'X' && b !== 'O') {
        b = "O";
        return b;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.67) {
        if (c !== 'X' && c !== 'O') {
        c = "O";
        return c;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.56) {
        if (d !== 'X' && d !== 'O') {
        d = "O";
        return d;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.45) {
        if (e !== 'X' && e !== 'O') {
        e = "O";
        return e;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.34) {
        if (f !== 'X' && f !== 'O') {
        f = "O";
        return f;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random> 0.23) {
        if (g !== 'X' && g !== 'O') {
        g = "O";
        return g;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.12) {
        if (h !== 'X' && h !== 'O') {
        h = "O";
        return h;
        } else {return randomNumber();}
    } else if (random > 0.00) {
        if (i !== 'X' && i !== 'O') {
        i = "O";
        return i;
        } else {
            return randomNumber();
        }
    }
}

//////////PLAYER MOVE VALIDATOR///////////
function playerMove() {
    var player = getInput();
        if (player === a && a !== 'X') {
            a = 'X';
        } else if (player === b && b !== 'X') {
            b = 'X';
        } else if (player === c && c !== 'X') {
            c = 'X';
        } else if (player === d && d !== 'X') {
            d = 'X';
        } else if (player === e && e !== 'X') {
            e = 'X';
        } else if (player === f && f !== 'X') {
            f = 'X';
        } else if (player === g && g !== 'X') {
            g = 'X';
        } else if (player === h && h !== 'X') {
            h = 'X';
        } else if (player === i && i !== 'X') {
            i = 'X';
        } else {
            console.log("=======" + "\n" + "Position already occupied" + "\n" + "Please Select Again" + "\n" + "=======");
            buildBoard();
            playerMove();
        }
}

function compare() {
    var p = playerMove();
    var cpu = randomNumber();
}


//////MAIN///////
function play() {
    buildBoard();
    compare();

    if (winner('X')) {
        buildBoard();
        console.log('You win!');
        return 'X';
    } else if (winner('O')) {
        buildBoard();
        console.log('The computer wins!');
        return 'O';
    } else {
        play();
    }
}

/////////DETERMINE WINNER IF WINNER FUNCTION STACK IS TRUE/////////////

////////TOP OF WINNER STACK////////////
function winner(player) {
    return winsRow(player) || winsColumn(player) || winsDiagonal(player);   
}

function winsRow(player) {
    return allThree(player, a, b, c) ||
           allThree(player, d, e, f) ||
           allThree(player, g, h ,i);
}

function winsColumn(player) {
    return allThree(player, a, d, g) ||
           allThree(player, b, e, h) ||
           allThree(player, c, f, i);
}
function winsDiagonal(player) {
    return allThree(player, a, e, i) ||
           allThree(player, c, e, g);
}
function allThree(player, cell_one, cell_two, cell_three) {
    return (cell_one === player) && (cell_two === player) && (cell_three === player);
}
/////////BOTTOM OF WINNER STACK///////////
```

Comment: At the start the board, the board assignment is redundant.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Please write all suggestions for improvements as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using individual variables to represent the cells in the game, it makes more sense to use a data structure like an array to represent the entire board.  This also allows you to simple index into the array rather than having to make a giant switch/if statement in the player and cpu move functions.

Additionally, by keeping the labels separate from the board, we can simply check if a board cell is empty by `!board[index]` rather than having to check that it is not `'X'` and not `'O'`: `(cell !== 'X' && cell !== 'O')`.

Storing the labels in a string allows us to index in there on the player's input to get a board index easily: `boardLabels.indexOf(prompt(msg))`.

Full code below:

```
///////TicTacToe///////////

//////////BOARD ASSIGNMENT////////////
var board = [];
var boardLabels = 'abcdefghi';

play();

function buildBoard() {
    var boardString = "=======" + "\n";
    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
        boardString += (board[i] || boardLabels[i]) + "|";
        boardString += (board[i+1] || boardLabels[i+1]) + "|";
        boardString += (board[i+2] || boardLabels[i+2]) + "\n";
    }
    boardString += "=======";
    console.log(boardString);
    return board;
}

/////////PLAYER INPUT///////////
function getInput(){
    var msg = "You are X, the computer is O" + "\n" +
        "X goes first"
    console.log(msg);
    return boardLabels.indexOf(prompt(msg));
}

//////////CPU MOVE GENERATOR///////////
function getRandomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
}

//////////CPU MOVE VALIDATOR///////////
function cpuMove() {
    var randomIndex = getRandomNumber();
    if(!board[randomIndex]) {
        board[randomIndex] = "O";
    } else {
        cpuMove();
    }
}

//////////PLAYER MOVE VALIDATOR///////////
function playerMove() {
    var chosenIndex = getInput();
    if(!board[chosenIndex]) {
        board[chosenIndex] = 'X';
    } else {
        console.log("=======" + "\n" + "Position already occupied" + "\n" + "Please Select Again" + "\n" + "=======");
        buildBoard();
        playerMove();
    }
}

function compare() {
    playerMove();
    cpuMove();
}


//////MAIN///////
function play() {
    buildBoard();
    compare();

    if (winner('X')) {
        buildBoard();
        console.log('You win!');
        return 'X';
    } else if (winner('O')) {
        buildBoard();
        console.log('The computer wins!');
        return 'O';
    } else {
        play();
    }
}

/////////DETERMINE WINNER IF WINNER FUNCTION STACK IS TRUE/////////////

////////TOP OF WINNER STACK////////////
function winner(player) {
    return winsRow(player) || winsColumn(player) || winsDiagonal(player);   
}

function winsRow(player) {
    return allThree(player, 0, 1, 2) ||
           allThree(player, 3, 4, 5) ||
           allThree(player, 6, 7 ,8);
}

function winsColumn(player) {
    return allThree(player, 0, 3, 6) ||
           allThree(player, 1, 4, 7) ||
           allThree(player, 2, 5, 8);
}
function winsDiagonal(player) {
    return allThree(player, 0, 4, 8) ||
           allThree(player, 2, 4, 6);
}
function allThree(player, cell_one, cell_two, cell_three) {
    return (board[cell_one] === player) && (board[cell_two] === player) && (board[cell_three] === player);
}
/////////BOTTOM OF WINNER STACK///////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array (as the previous answer mentions) will also cut a lot of hard-coding and repetitive typing out of your "winner" functions. It requires another variable at the start of your program:

```
var board = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var labels = 'abcdefghi';
var wins = [
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  [0,3,6],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [0,4,8],
  [2,4,6]
 ];
```

You can now use a loop in a single `isWinner` function which checks to see if one player occupies the three squares for a win condition. It has the added value of returning the winner 'x' or 'o' if there is one:

```
function isWinner(board){
  for(var i=0; i<this.wins.length; i++){
    var a, b, c;
    //these varaibles become what the board is holding 'x', 'o', or 0
    a = board[wins[i][0]];
    b = board[wins[i][1]];
    c = board[wins[i][2]];

    if(a == b && a == c && a != 0){
      return a;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```